# Fire a jquery onclick event on submitting the form, after successful validation

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have a JSP form which does validation using `jquery.validate()` plugin. 
On clicking the submit button i need to show a div which shows the progress bar gif image. **But I want to show this only after the form validation is successful and the contents are passed to the server.**

I wrote the jquery on the onclick event of the button.

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $('#loading').show();
  });
```

But the problem is the progress bar is being displayed on every button click for each validation.  How to make the progress bar visible not on every button click but on a button submit after successful validation?

Answer (score 1):

```
 submitHandler: function(form) {
             if ($("form").valid()) {
                 $('#loading').show();
                 form.submit();
             }
         }
```

This solved the issue :)

Comment: Yes, using the `submitHandler` is the correct answer.  However, you don't need the conditional `if .valid()` part.  That's because, by definition, the `submitHandler` ONLY fires if the form is valid.  Your conditional will never fail, therefore it's superfluous.  See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler

Answer (score -1):

try this one

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    var fun_call=your_validation_function();//Call here your validation function
    if(fun_call==true)
    {    
        $('#loading').show();
    }
});
```